# How to pass the initial value to foldLeft from a filtered List with function chaining?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Say I have a `List`. I `filter` it first on some condition. Now I want to pass the initial value from this filtered array to `foldLeft` all while chaining both together. Is there a way to do that?

For example:

```
scala> val numbers = List(5, 4, 8, 6, 2)
val numbers: List[Int] = List(5, 4, 8, 6, 2)

scala> numbers.filter(_ % 2 == 0).foldLeft(numbers(0)) { // this is obviously incorrect since numbers(0) is the value at index 0 of the original array not the filtered array
     |   (z, i) => z + i
     | }
val res88: Int = 25
```

Comment: Maybe just use `reduceLeft` or even better you can just `.sum`. Even better, do everything in one go `numbers.withFilter(_ % 2 == 0).sum` _(`withFiler` is **lazy**, if you have many more steps, you can use an **Iterator** instead, so all the steps are lazily evaluated)_. - BTW, it is confusing to call a **List** an **Array**.

Comment: Using a first element for a fold is quite unusual, you usually use a zero (or some other element serving as "empty" for the fold operation). Are you really sure you want to do that?

Comment: @Suma @jwvh This was just a simplified example, I do intend to use `foldLeft` like this but not how I showed in the example code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just pattern match on the result of filtering to get the first element of list (head) and the rest (tail):

```
val numbers = List(5, 4, 8, 6, 2)

val result = numbers.filter(_ % 2 == 0) match {
  case head :: tail => tail.foldLeft(head) {
        (z, i) => z + i
  }
   // here you need to handle the case, when after filtering there are no elements, in this case, I just return 0
  case Nil => 0
}
```

You could also just use reduce:

```
numbers.filter(_ % 100 == 0).reduce {
   (z, i) => z + i
}
```

but it will throw an exception in case after filtering the list is empty.

Comment: Or simply `case nonempty @ _ :: _ => nonempty.reduce`?

Comment: you cannot reduce an empty collection - it will throw error => foldLeft is safer